# Why I cannot parse this HTML page in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the information in the web page http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2000-pitching.shtml in Python using BeautifulSoup. I want to print out the corresponding name of each player for the table "Team Pitching”. However, the code is repeating the name of the players after some particular name (in this case after row 15, it repeats the name 'Pedro Martinez'). For example:

```
1 Pedro Martinez
2 Jeff Fassero*
3 Ramon Martinez
4 Pete Schourek*
5 Rolando Arrojo
6 Tomo Ohka
7 Derek Lowe
8 Tim Wakefield
9 Rich Garces
10 Rheal Cormier*
11 Hipolito Pichardo
12 Brian Rose
13 Bryce Florie
14 John Wasdin
15 Pedro Martinez
16 Jeff Fassero*
17 Ramon Martinez
18 Pete Schourek*
19 Rolando Arrojo
20 Tomo Ohka
21 Derek Lowe
22 Tim Wakefield
23 Rich Garces
24 Rheal Cormier*
25 Hipolito Pichardo
26 Brian Rose
27 Bryce Florie
28 John Wasdin
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening? This is my code:

```
# Sample web page
#http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2000-pitching.shtml


import urllib2
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Download webpages 2010 webpage

y = 2000
url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/'+ str(y) +'-pitching.shtml'
print 'Download from :', url

#dowlnload
filehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)


fileout = 'YEARS'+str(y)+'.html'
print 'Save to : ', fileout, '\n'

#save file to disk
f = open(fileout,'w')
f.write(filehandle.read())
f.close()


# Read and parse the html file

# Parse information about the age of players in 2000

y = 2000

filein = 'YEARS' + str(y) + '.html'
print(filein)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filein))


entries = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : ''}) #' non_qual' ''
print(len(entries)) 

i = 0
for entry in entries:


    columns = entry.find_all('td')  
    #print(len(columns), 'i:', i)
    if len (columns)==34: # Number of columns of the table

        i = i + 1

        #print i, len(columns)  
        age = columns[2].get_text()

        print i, age
```

Comment: do you want to extract? Also what and where is table?

Comment: The code you show is broken in two ways -- uses variables `year` and `table`, never defined.  Fixing it to use `y` and `soup` instead, it runs fine -- does **not** reproduce the bug you mention (and there's no "Pedro Martinez" in 2010: it's John Lackey, Jon Lester, etc).

Comment: Using 2000 (as mentioned in your text) rather than 2010 (as in your code), and again with the fix above wrt variable names, #1 is indeed Pedro Martinez, but, again, no bug -- #15 is Rod Beck, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to loop through all the rows in the table, without actually getting all the table tags first. So you get all the table tags, then loop through all the tr tags in the table tags, if that makes sense. Also `year` and `table` were undefined, so I assumed year was `y` and made the `table` variable `t`. As a side note, you don't have to download the HTML and then open it to parse it, you can just get the HTML by getting the text of the connection and parsing directly.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Download webpages 2010 webpage

y = 2010
url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/'+ str(y) +'-pitching.shtml'
print 'Download from :', url

#dowlnload
filehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)


fileout = 'YEARS'+str(y)+'.html'
print 'Save to : ', fileout, '\n'

#save file to disk
f = open(fileout,'w')
f.write(filehandle.read())
f.close()


# Read and parse the html file

# Parse information about the age of players in 2000

y = 2010

filein = 'YEARS' + str(y) + '.html'
print(filein)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filein))


table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'team_pitching'}) #' non_qual' ''


for t in table:

    i = 1
    entries = t.find_all('tr', attrs={'class' : ''}) #' non_qual' ''
    print(len(entries))
    for entry in entries:
        columns = entry.find_all('td')
        printString = str(i) + ' '
        for col in columns:
            try:
                if ((',' in col['csk']) and (col['csk'] != '')):
                    printString = printString + col.text
                    i = i + 1
                    print printString
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: heinst, your recommendation makes sense at all. However, the program is still repeating names after row 15, I mean it starts again in Pedro Martinez? Any idea?

Comment: I dont see pedro martinez anywhere on the table @Paul

Comment: I am using data from 2000 instead 2010. But I still see the problem after row 15 @heinst

Comment: @Paul Yeah I see it now, this method works for sure!

Comment: Thanks @heinst, it works for 2010. Do you have any idea why this method does not work for data in 2000?

Comment: Thank you for your response @heinst, I tried for 2000 but I have the same repeating stream. Ex: 15 Rod Beck
15 Rod BeckPedro Martinez
15 Rod BeckPedro MartinezJeff Fassero*
15 Rod BeckPedro MartinezJeff Fassero*Ramon Martinez
15 Rod BeckPedro MartinezJeff Fassero*Ramon MartinezPete Schourek*
15 Rod BeckPedro MartinezJeff Fassero*Ramon MartinezPete Schourek*Rolando Arrojo ...

Comment: @Paul Maybe try clearing the HTML files? Making sure you have the latest BeautifulSoup? I am using python 2.7. I do not see the same results as you